# Importance of Gödel Numbering System

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, incompleteness

How important is Gödel numbering to his incompleteness proofs, set theory, logic theory in general and proofs employing ZFC? Can we use some other numbering or 'meta' programming?

How about if one uses a more efficient numbering system? How efficient can the numbering system be in order for his proofs to work?

Comment: The details of the indexing are not of particular importance. That it **can** be done is very important.

Comment: To add to what @André says, it is even *more* important that it can be done *recursively*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila what do you mean about recursion here? I am just seeing he used Chinese Remaindering or something along those lines.

Comment: The set of integers which encode a wff formula is recursive, which is an important feature in the proofs.

Comment: It is also important because it removes any "self referential" formulas, even though their description may seem self referential.